# How to return a Unity floating license?

Tags: unity-game-engine, continuous-integration

I'm using Windows.

`Unity.Licensing.Client.exe` has a `--return-floating` option, but it requires the UUID of the lease.

How do I find the UUID of that lease?

There seems to be no option to list current leases associated with the machine or user. Some people say there's a directory where it keeps licenses, but I don't see any relevant changes in the filesystem where you might expect Unity to store local or application data, either.

Comment: seems C:\ProgramData\Unity\Unity_lic.ulf is where mines at.. not sure why you didnt find it , the file location is listed in the Unity.Licensing.Client.log and it and the license is touched every day to update the date.. so..

Comment: @BugFinder That's a personal license. This is a floating license that is obtained from the Unity Licensing Server, it's used in an enterprise environment to license entire farms of machines that are running Unity jobs.

Comment: then you'd best ask unity, i am surprised they do different coding for different licenses

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I realized it was printing the token on STDOUT the whole time:

```
Client product version: 1.6.2+1.91f8005
Trying to acquire floating license from: 123.456.789.999 ...
License lease Created with token bdb2238d-7ee8-41ef-ba58-782daeecc675. Expires: Wednesday, September 20, 2023 5:42:39 PM
```

So that's easy to solve, I just parse STDOUT and keep that token around to return later.